# List find method finds nothing, but let is called (?!)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

i have the following code:

```
            myList.find { it.code == item.bin }.let {
               // 1

            } ?: run {
               // 2
                
            }
```

I would expect that, if item is found, I enter block 1 , otherwise block 2 ;
But instead I enter block 1 in all cases, and if nothing is found , it is null

Android studio seems aware of this, as the block 2 is grey (it is code never called), but I can't figure why

Please may someone explain why ?

Comment: @takecare has answered correctly: you need to use the safe call operator before the _let_ to be able to use the _elvis operator_ 'else' clause. I would recommend to not use _find_, but _firstOrNull_ which makes the intention more clear. Also _find_ is an alias of _firstOrNull_ and _find_ is apparently kept just for lowering the bar for programmers new to Kotlin (see for example the discussion here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5185).

Comment: Advice: never use the `?.let { } ?: run { }` pattern because it is extremely error prone. You can easily cause both lambdas to be called depending on what the resulting value of the let call is. Plus, it’s just plain hard to read. But if you insisted on using this pattern despite the bad readability, you would want to use `also` instead of `let` to guard against this risk. Much better to use if/else though.

Answer (score 2):

`null` is still a value so it makes sense that the first block is run. it'd be the same as if you ran `null.let { println("hey!") }`.

you probably want to run `let` with a null check: `myList.find { it.code == item.bin }?.let { ... }`. this way the block will only run if there is indeed a value being returned that is not null.

Comment: yes, this was the problem, thanks ; I usually program in Swift and let is different there

Answer (score 1):

You are using classic dot call operator `.`, this operator is not allowed on nullable types. If you want to call this operator on nullable type insert `!!` before operator, but if you call it on `null` it throws NullPointerException

You have to use Kotlins [safe call operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls) `?.`, which call method when insatce is not `null` and when is it returns `null`.

`?:` operator is called [Elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) and it returns first value if it is not `null`, else it returns second value.

So just change in your code dot operator `.` to safe call operator `?.`:

```
myList.find { it.code == item.bin }.let {
               // 1

            } ?: run {
               // 2
                
            }
```

Comment: ?. is the solution, anyway it does not throw any exception